# Java - Not getting the timestamp for a specific timezone

Tags: java, timezone

In the below code, i m trying to get dateformat for timezone PST, but i didnt get the expected output.
But, If I uncomment the 2 lines (setDefault timezone), i m getting the expected results.

Do you have any good option?

```
    System.out.println("TimeZone.getDefault():"+TimeZone.getDefault()); // CST
   //TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(SimpleTimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
  //Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    Date c = cal.getTime();
    String out = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMddyyyy").format(c);
    System.out.println("out:"+out);
```

If the current date in CST is February082015 (at night 12 to 2 AM), then the expected output for PST would be February072015 (PST is 2hrs behind CST). But, I m getting the output as February082015.

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the result you are getting?

Comment: If the current date in CST is February082015 (at night 12 to 1 AM), then the expected output for PST would be February072015 (PST is 2hrs behind CST). But, I m getting the output as February082015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DateFormat` doesn't inherit a `TimeZone` from the `Calender`. To demonstrate, I've added a `Z` (which will display the time-zone offset). Run it with and without setting the `TimeZone` and your observed behavior is explained

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMddyyyy Z"); // <-- The Z is TZ
df.setTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")); // <-- Add/Remove this
String out = df.format(c);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Actually, I don't want to change the format. I m getting "out:February082015 -0600" as output if i run the above.

Comment: That is PST. Remove the Z then.

Comment: I didn't notice the timezone set at the dateformat object.

Comment: Thank you.!! Its working.,   SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMddyyyy");
  df.setTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
  System.out.println("out:"+df.format(c));

Comment: There's no need to use the full package name on the right hand side of the `df` assignment. Also, I recommend that you prefer the `DateFormat` interface on the left hand side.